# Cant log out of cookie/session PHP

Tags: php, html, session, cookies

Hi have some scripts but they wont log out. It looks like its logged out but then I go back to the browser and its still active... My code is as follows.

```
    }
    define("G_MD5KEY", 'aFTRW#$Rjsdh');
    Am_Controller::setCookie("cookie_login", $event->getUser()->login, time()+3600);
    Am_Controller::setCookie("cookie_password", md5($this->getPass($event->getUser()).G_MD5KEY),time()+3600);
    $this->getAPI()->efrontlogin(array('login' =>$event->getUser()->login));

}

function onAuthAfterLogout(Am_Event_AuthAfterLogout $event)
{
    Am_Controller::setCookie('cookie_login',"", time()-3600*24);
    Am_Controller::setCookie('cookie_password',"", time()-3600*24);
    $this->getAPI()->efrontlogout(array('login' =>$event->getUser()->login));

}
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: md5 password stored in a cookie....yum

Comment: double-rot13-encoded, for extra security?  :)

Comment: I dont know, I didnt write this it just isnt working...

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I see you didn't write this code.
There can be at least 100 possibilites for why you're still "logged-in" even after
trying to "logout".

Use chrome in order to check which cookies and what values ,  you have before logging-out and after.
Another thing you should check is the condition which detrmining if you're logged-in or not,
maybe the condition is just looking for the existence of the cookie and not check it's value.